# Dont output any duplicate values to a csv file

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I am converting a json file to a csv file. I am outputting four columns in my csv file but I dont want to output any duplicate values.

I am adding variables to an array and outputting them to a csv file and if there are any duplicate values in the 'Name' column so if a duplicate occurs then dont add it to the output. I am not really sure how to go about this.

```
 ForEach ($fileEnvironment in $jsonVariables.ScopeValues.Environments) { 
        #Create empty array
        $dataArray = @()

      ForEach ($fileVariable in $jsonVariables.Variables) {
         if($fileVariable.Description -eq $null) {
            $fileVariable.Description = 'No Description'
        }
            if (!!$fileVariable.Scope) {
                if (!!$fileVariable.Scope.Environment) {
                    if ($fileEnvironment.Id -eq $fileVariable.Scope.Environment[0]) {                   
                        #Add fileVariable to the array
                        $dataArray += $fileVariable

                    } 
                }
            }
        }

  $filename="$($outputPath)\$($projectName)_$($fileEnvironment.Name).csv"
            if ($dataArray.Count -ne 0) {
                 $dataArray | Select-Object -Property 
  Name,Type,Value,Description | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 
  $fileName
        }
```

I dont want the Name column to have duplicate values so as you can see apiconfig is repeated and I would like only to have one apiconfig outputted to csv. In the csv file output is like:
    Name          Type       Value    Description
    apiConfig     String      ...        No Description
    apiconfig     String      ...        No Description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) to filter out duplicates.

Here is a console log that illustrates the idea.

```bsh
$listWithDuplicates = @([PSCustomObject]@{Name="A";Desc="1"},[PSCustomObject]@{Name="A";Desc="2"},[PSCustomObject]@{Name="B";Desc="3"})

▷ $listWithDuplicates

Name Desc
---- ----
A    1
A    2
B    3

▷ $set = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]"
▷ $listWithoutDuplicates = $listWithDuplicates  |? {$set.Add($_.Name)}
▷ $listWithoutDuplicates

Name Desc
---- ----
A    1
B    3
```